# Launching mono exe file within emacs/Fsharp mode

Tags: emacs, f#, elisp

I'm using [Fsharp mode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsharp-mode/) in emacs.
The key of `^C x` is mapped to `Run ...` command which is as follows.

```
(defun fsharp-run-executable-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (string-match "^\\(.*\\)\\.\\(fs\\|fsi\\)$" name)
        (shell-command (concat (match-string 1 name) ".exe")))))
```

The problem is that it tries to run `bash something.exe`, whereas I need to run the command of `mono something.exe`. I got error message of `/bin/bash ...exe: cannot execute binary file`.

How can I come up with a new elisp command to launch mono, and then get the result to show it to `*compilation*` buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine fsharp-run-executable-file and use this one instead:

```
(defun fsharp-run-executable-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (string-match "^\\(.*\\)\\.\\(fs\\|fsi\\)$" name)
        (compile (concat "mono " (match-string 1 name) ".exe")))))
```

There are two changes: 1) concat `mono` before the command (as petebu wrote); 2) use the `compile` function so that the output is in the `*compilation*` buffer.

To test quickly, just evaluate the above function (add it in your Emacs init file for a permanent change). Note that you shouldn't modify fsharp.el file, at I might update at some point (you don't want to lost your changes).

**Edit**

One issue with the previous function is that it modifies the last compilation command. This might might annoying if you compile your code with `compile` or `recompile` commands. Here is a fix:

```
(defun fsharp-run-executable-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (string-match "^\\(.*\\)\\.\\(fs\\|fsi\\)$" name)
        (compilation-start (concat "mono " (match-string 1 name) ".exe")))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try changing the last line to:

```
(shell-command (concat "mono " (match-string 1 name) ".exe")))))
```

but I haven't tested this.